# How can I resolve this problem on Laravel [view.engine.resolver]

Tags: php, laravel

When I run any PHP artisant command I got this Error

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\project_final-pfe>php artisan route:list             

   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException 

  Target class [view.engine.resolver] does not exist.

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\project_final-pfe\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:879
    875▕ 
    876▕         try {
    877▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    878▕         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  ➜ 879▕             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    880▕         }
    881▕
    882▕         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    883▕         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

  1   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(Facade\Ignition\IgnitionServiceProvider))

  2   C:\xampp\htdocs\project_final-pfe\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:877
      ReflectionException::("Class "view.engine.resolver" does not exist")
```

Comment: Are you sure about that, the vendor folder has all files and classes? is it complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Delete the `vendor` folder.
2. If you are in development delete the `composer.lock` file.
3. Run `composer install`
4. Try again your command: `php artisan route:list`

**Update - 15.02.2022**

Issue is related to package `livewire:livewire` and the solution according to the git repo is :

- Disabling auto-discovery of the `livewire/livewire` package using the `extra.laravel.dont-discover` property in `composer.json`.
- Registering `Livewire\LivewireServiceProvider::class` manually in `config/app.php`.

Source:
https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/384

Comment: I do all this steps but it doesn't work

Comment: I guess you use livewire. Try: composer require livewire/livewire.

Comment: the same problem bro when I require livewire they gives me the same problem Target class [view.engine.resolver] does not exist

Comment: check my answer. I updated.

Comment: doesn't work bro idk why they just give me the same error

Comment: check the source I added above.